# SIGABRT on Startup in Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, sigabrt

I was just running my code on the simulator which has been working in the past. The only thing I've really done for the startup code is setting user defaults

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"Automatic", @"userType",
                             @"NO", @"autoRefresh",
                             @"60", @"refreshInt", nil
                            ];

[defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
[defaults synchronize];
```

I ran the app 10 times on my iPhone/iPad and experienced no crashing on startup. However, if I run it on the iPhone/iPad Simulator, the iPhone simulator crashes with SIGABRT basically every other time. I am not sure what's causing this as I've already restarted my computer and did a "Reset all Contents and settings" on the simulator.

Thanks!
Alan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running Xcode 4.6.2 on OSX 10.8.4, try upgrading to Xcode 4.6.3 which was just released a few days ago. The 4.6.3 version has fixes for the random crashes and hangs that sometimes happens when debugging on the ios simulator.

Comment: I had suddenly experienced a series of SIGABRT crashes in the iOS Simulator (no stack traces), and was concerned I had broken something. However, it was actually due to the fact that I had just upgraded from OSX 10.8.3 to 10.8.4, earlier today. As you say, there is an update to Xcode in the Mac App Store, and it explicitly states it solves crashes of Xcode on 10.8.4. Thanks for pointing this up.

Comment: Yea, I just updated to the new xCode seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the lldb in chord with the newest version of Moutain Lion. If you want to avoid this switch to using GDB